# How to combine two elements of a list based on a given condition

Tags: python

I want to combine two elements in a list based on a given condition.

For example if I encounter the character `'a'` in a list, I would like to combine it with the next element. The list:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd']
```

becomes

```
['ab', 'c', 'ad']
```

Is there any quick way to do this?

One solution I have thought of is to create a new empty list and iterate through the first list. As we encounter the element `'a'` in list 1, we join *list1[index of a]* and *list1[index of a + 1]* and append the result to list 2. However I wanted to know if there is any way to do it without creating a new list and copying values into it.

Comment: You can modify the list on-the-fly with your algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does not create a new list, just modifies the existing one.

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd']
for i in range(len(l)-2, -1, -1):
    if l[i] == 'a':
        l[i] = l[i] + l.pop(i+1)
print(l)
```

Comment: The crucial detail here seems to be that the list is processed in reverse. You might want to explain why this is a good idea.

Comment: @mkrieger1 you get out index in l.pop(i+1) if you start with `for i in range(len(l))`

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use list comprehension to create a new list (maybe because your input list is huge) you could modify the list in-place:

```
i=0
while i < len(l):
 if l[i]=='a':
  l[i] += l.pop(i+1)
  i += 1
```

Comment: Elegant solution but you are not showing a key part of your code: what is `i` initialized to at the beginning?

Comment: you are missing `i++` simply put, you code doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks again! bad copy-paste on my part. Note though that python has no `++` operator, so you have to use `i += 1`

Answer (score 2):

Use a *list comprehension* with an iterator on your list. When the current iteratee is `a` simply join it with the next item from the iterator using `next`:

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd']

it = iter(l)
l[:] =  [i+next(it) if i == 'a' else i for i in it]
print l
# ['ab', 'c', 'ad']
```

Comment: List comprehension is creating a new list, thus contradicting with the user's requirements `without creating a new list `

Comment: @EyuelDK Well about a full slice assignment to the original list?

Comment: It Still creates a new list, but you just reassigned the elements to the slice. It still does not modify in place. To summarize, if you are using a list comprehension, it is creating a new list.

Comment: @EyuelDK Depends on what create a new list really means in this context. The `range` you've used in your solution creates a new list in Python 2.

Comment: You are right, in python 2.7 but I think that isn't relevant for this problem. It is implied that the user didn't want to create a new list of the original list, my use of range is irrelevant - can be fixed by using Python 3 or just a while statement, it isn't an issue. But what you are doing is creating a new list and then reassigning to the original list - just in a fancy syntax. That's why I think it doesn't meet requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't want to create a new list *so much*, here we go:

```
from itertools import islice

a = list("abcdabdbac")

i = 0
for x, y in zip(a, islice(a, 1, None)):
    if x == 'a':
        a[i] = x + y
        i += 1
    elif y != 'a':
        a[i] = y
        i += 1

try:
    del a[i:]
except:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use `itertools.groupby` and group by:

- letter follows `a` or
- letter is not `a`

using `enumerate` to generate the current index, which allows to fetch the previous element from the list (creating a new list but one-liner)

```
import itertools

l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd']

print(["".join(x[1] for x in v) for _,v in itertools.groupby(enumerate(l),key=lambda t: (t[0] > 0 and l[t[0]-1]=='a') or t[1]=='a')])
```

result:

```
['ab', 'c', 'ad']
```

Answer (score -1):

This is easy way. Mb not pythonic way.

```
l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd']

do_combine = False
combine_element = None
for el in l1:
    if do_combine:
        indx = l1.index(el)
        l1[indx] = combine_element + el 
        do_combine = False
        l1.remove(combine_element)
    if el == 'a':
        combine_element = el
        do_combine = True

print(l1)
    # ['ab', 'c', 'ad']
```